# Alexa BDD tests

Tags: java, testing, oauth-2.0, bdd, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to implement BDD test on my Alexa skill. I am using Java SDK to implement it.

Basically, I would like to trigger arbitrary intents programmatically in my test suite and assert on responses, but I could not find any materials to implement it.

All I could find is `com.amazon.ask.model.services.skillMessaging.SkillMessagingServiceClient.sendSkillMessage`, whose Javadoc says:

> Send a message request to a skill for a specified user.

That would be what I need, but, in order to create a `com.amazon.ask.model.services.skillMessaging.SkillMessagingServiceClient`, I have to do the following:

```
SkillMessagingServiceClient client = new SkillMessagingServiceClient(
                DefaultApiConfiguration.builder()
                        .withApiClient(ApacheHttpApiClient.standard())
                        .withSerializer(new JacksonSerializer())
                        .withAuthorizationValue("<authorization_token").build(),
                DefaultAuthenticationConfiguration.builder()
                        .withClientId("<client_id>")
                        .withClientSecret("<client_secret>")
                        .build()
        );
```

In order to get `client_id` and `client_secret`:

1. I have accessed *Login with Amazon Console*
2. I have created a security profile
3. I have enabled *Account Linking* on my skill, with

   1. Authorization URI: `https://www.amazon.com/ap/oa`
   2. Access token URI: `https://api.amazon.com/auth/o2/token`
   3. Client ID and Client secret as from point 2
   4. Scopes: `alexa:skill_messaging` and `profile:user_id`
   5. Authentication schema: Basic
4. I have copied all the *Alexa Redirect URLs* in the allowed return web URIs in my security profile

As a result, now my skill could be bound to my Amazon account from Alexa app, but:

1. All in all, I just wanted to implement tests, NOT bind my account. My skill in production does not need this feature
2. The binding does not work: after confirming it from Alexa app, I receive an error
3. Yet I do not know how to collect the authentication token, unless I catch it from Cloudwatch log and use it... until it expires

At point 2, I could see the reason of the failure: `oauthError` (`https://skills-store.amazon.it/external/link-result?success=false&errorKey=oauth-error&languageCode=it_IT&skillId=amzn1.ask.skill......&skillStage=development`). The web page contains a link to RFC6749.

I am currently stuck and I can not test my skill completely, also because it is impossible to test Alexa Player, especially in Italian, unless you directly test it using a physical device.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are confused between account linking and skill credentials. Account linking is for making api calls to external services on behalf of the user, E.G. I want my skill able to access user's google profile.

Thus for your use case, skill credentials which used to make API calls to skill-related Alexa services seems good enough. Since you already got the clientId, client secrect, I would recommend you explore the [Ask-Smapi-Sdk](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-skills-kit-sdk-for-java/tree/2.0.x/ask-smapi-sdk). You could follow the readme to retrieve the refreshToken through ask-cli, and build smapi client. 
With SmapiClient, you could use Smapi simulate apis to trigger your intents, specially the function [simulateSkillV1](https://github.com/alexa/alexa-apis-for-java/blob/master/ask-smapi-model/src/com/amazon/ask/model/services/skillManagement/SkillManagementServiceClient.java#L2564) defined in your smapi Client.

Hope this is what you need. ✧(•̀ω•́ )

Thanks,
Shen

Comment: maybe you could help me with this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59435963/ssl-exception-received-close-notify-during-handshake-upon-initializing-alexa.