# SSL exception: "received close_notify during handshake" upon initializing Alexa Skill Management API (SMAPI)

Tags: java, ssl, alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to use SMAPI to interact with my Alexa Skill using Java.

The following code fails:

```
package io.mirko.impl;

import com.amazon.ask.model.services.skillManagement.SkillManagementService;
import com.amazon.ask.smapi.SmapiClients;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

public class IntegrationTest {
    // These come from `ask util generate-lwa-tokens` passing ClientID and SecretID from LWA
    private static final String CLIENT_ID = "<client_id>";
    private static final String CLIENT_SECRET = "<client_secret>";
    private static final String REFRESH_TOKEN = "<refresh_token>";
    private static final String SKILL_ID = "<skill_id>";
    @Test
    public void test() {
        final SkillManagementService smapiClient = SmapiClients.createDefault(
                CLIENT_ID,
                CLIENT_SECRET,
                REFRESH_TOKEN
        );
        System.out.println(smapiClient.getSkillManifestV1(SKILL_ID, "developement"));
    }
}
```

You can find the SSL logs at [this link](https://gist.github.com/fcracker79/4d34e7f4535904860894fbbb0a0354e1)
The failure is the following:

```
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Received close_notify during handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:126)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:255)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:244)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at com.amazon.ask.services.ApacheHttpApiClient.invoke(ApacheHttpApiClient.java:70)
    at com.amazon.ask.model.services.BaseServiceClient.executeRequest(BaseServiceClient.java:124)
    at com.amazon.ask.model.services.BaseServiceClient.invoke(BaseServiceClient.java:87)
    at com.amazon.ask.model.services.lwa.LwaClient.generateAccessToken(LwaClient.java:112)
    at com.amazon.ask.model.services.lwa.LwaClient.getAccessTokenForScope(LwaClient.java:82)
    at com.amazon.ask.model.services.lwa.LwaClient.getAccessTokenForRefreshToken(LwaClient.java:65)
    at com.amazon.ask.model.services.skillManagement.SkillManagementServiceClient.callGetSkillManifestV1(SkillManagementServiceClient.java:3484)
    at com.amazon.ask.model.services.skillManagement.SkillManagementServiceClient.getSkillManifestV1(SkillManagementServiceClient.java:3513)
    at io.mirko.impl.IntegrationTest.test(IntegrationTest.java:20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)}

)
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-12-21 12:34:44.530 CET|SSLSocketImpl.java:1361|close the underlying socket
javax.net.ssl|DEBUG|01|main|2019-12-21 12:34:44.531 CET|SSLSocketImpl.java:1380|close the SSL connection (passive)


com.amazon.ask.model.services.ServiceException: Call to service failed: There was an error executing the request

    at com.amazon.ask.model.services.BaseServiceClient.executeRequest(BaseServiceClient.java:126)
    at com.amazon.ask.model.services.BaseServiceClient.invoke(BaseServiceClient.java:87)
    at com.amazon.ask.model.services.lwa.LwaClient.generateAccessToken(LwaClient.java:112)
    at com.amazon.ask.model.services.lwa.LwaClient.getAccessTokenForScope(LwaClient.java:82)
    at com.amazon.ask.model.services.lwa.LwaClient.getAccessTokenForRefreshToken(LwaClient.java:65)
    at com.amazon.ask.model.services.skillManagement.SkillManagementServiceClient.callGetSkillManifestV1(SkillManagementServiceClient.java:3484)
    at com.amazon.ask.model.services.skillManagement.SkillManagementServiceClient.getSkillManifestV1(SkillManagementServiceClient.java:3513)
    at io.mirko.impl.IntegrationTest.test(IntegrationTest.java:20)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.junit.platform.commons.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:675)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.MethodInvocation.proceed(MethodInvocation.java:60)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$ValidatingInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:125)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.intercept(TimeoutExtension.java:132)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestableMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:124)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.extension.TimeoutExtension.interceptTestMethod(TimeoutExtension.java:74)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker$ReflectiveInterceptorCall.lambda$ofVoidMethod$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:115)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.lambda$invoke$0(ExecutableInvoker.java:105)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain$InterceptedInvocation.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.proceed(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:62)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.chainAndInvoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:43)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.InvocationInterceptorChain.invoke(InvocationInterceptorChain.java:35)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:104)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExecutableInvoker.invoke(ExecutableInvoker.java:98)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestMethod$6(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:202)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.invokeTestMethod(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:198)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:135)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.execute(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:69)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:38)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$5(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$7(NodeTestTask.java:125)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:135)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:122)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:80)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:32)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:51)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:229)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.lambda$execute$6(DefaultLauncher.java:197)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.withInterceptedStreams(DefaultLauncher.java:211)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:191)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:128)
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:69)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:33)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:230)
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: There was an error executing the request
    at com.amazon.ask.services.ApacheHttpApiClient.invoke(ApacheHttpApiClient.java:74)
    at com.amazon.ask.model.services.BaseServiceClient.executeRequest(BaseServiceClient.java:124)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: Received close_notify during handshake
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:126)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert.createSSLException(Alert.java:117)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:308)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:264)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:255)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.Alert$AlertConsumer.consume(Alert.java:244)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.dispatch(TransportContext.java:181)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:164)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1152)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1063)
    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:402)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
    at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
    at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
    at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
    at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:108)
    at com.amazon.ask.services.ApacheHttpApiClient.invoke(ApacheHttpApiClient.java:70)
    ... 71 more



Process finished with exit code 255
```

By contrast, the following vanilla Java code works perfectly and I can get the access token:

```
package io.mirko;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.client.protocol.HttpClientContext;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Main {
    private static final String HOST = "api.amazon.com";
    private static final String URL = String.format("https://%s/auth/O2/token", HOST);
    private static final String URL_PARAMETERS = "grant_type=refresh_token&client_id=<client_id>&client_secret=<client_secret>&refresh_token=<refresh_token>";

    private static String connectVanillaJava() throws Exception {
        byte[] postData = URL_PARAMETERS.getBytes( StandardCharsets.UTF_8 );
        int postDataLength = postData.length;
        URL url = new URL(URL);
        HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        conn.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
        conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", Integer.toString(postDataLength ));
        conn.setUseCaches(false);
        try(DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream())) {
            wr.write( postData );
        }
        DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
        byte[] data = new byte[32768];
        final ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        for (int i = is.read(data); i > 0; i = is.read(data)) {
            os.write(data, 0, i);
        }
        return new String(os.toByteArray());
    }

    public static void main(String ... args) throws Exception {
        System.out.print("Test Vanilla Java...");
        final String vanillaJavaResult = connectVanillaJava();
        System.out.format("SUCCESS!\nReturned %s\n", vanillaJavaResult);
    }
}
```

You can get [here](https://gist.github.com/fcracker79/81bc7a9fdc1dda4617b404c8aedf1c45) the SSL logs, together with th returned response,

The main difference I can see is that, after `Produced client Finished handshake message`, in the first case, after more than 10 seconds, I receive the error, whereas in the working example I receive `Consuming server Finished handshake message`.

Thanks for the help.

P.S. Based on the SSL logs differences, it seems to be that the broken interaction receives SSL certificates from `api.amazonalexa.com`, which is DOWN. By accessing that host in a browse, I receive [this message](http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/website/errors/503/generic.png). It says that the website is temporary unavailable.
I have modified the working example by using that host and it seems to be that I get the same error.

P.P.S. I managed to get the authentication token by creating an LWAClient using `api.amazon.com`. Any interaction with `api.amazonalexa.com` raises the above issue.

```
inal LwaClient lwaClient = LwaClient.builder()
                .withAuthenticationConfiguration(
                        DefaultAuthenticationConfiguration.builder()
                                .withClientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET)
                                .withClientId(CLIENT_ID)
                                .withRefreshToken(REFRESH_TOKEN)
                                .build()
                )
                .withGrantType(GrantType.REFRESH_TOKEN)
                .withApiConfiguration(DefaultApiConfiguration.builder()
                        .withApiClient(apiConfiguration.getApiClient())
                        // Without this, it does not work
                        .withApiEndpoint("https://api.amazon.com")
                        .withSerializer(apiConfiguration.getSerializer())
                        .build())
                .build();
        final SkillManagementServiceClient myClient = new SkillManagementServiceClient(
                apiConfiguration, lwaClient);
        // This WORKS
        System.out.println(lwaClient.getAccessTokenForRefreshToken());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I managed to solve the issue. 
By running the code in debug mode, it is possible to catch the request that is going to be run and that is related to the issue.
If you invoke that request using `curl`, you receive immediately an error that is 
self-explained:

```
curl -vvv -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer Atza|XXXXX" -d "{}" https://api.amazonalexa.com/v1/skills/<skill_id>/simulations
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 143.204.11.219...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to api.amazonalexa.com (143.204.11.219) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* TLSv1.3 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.3 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server accepted to use h2
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=api.amazonalexa.com
*  start date: May  3 00:00:00 2019 GMT
*  expire date: Apr 26 12:00:00 2020 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "api.amazonalexa.com" matched cert's "api.amazonalexa.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
* Using HTTP2, server supports multi-use
* Connection state changed (HTTP/2 confirmed)
* Copying HTTP/2 data in stream buffer to connection buffer after upgrade: len=0
* Using Stream ID: 1 (easy handle 0x55ba1fa314b0)
> POST /v1/skills/<skill_id>/simulations HTTP/2
> Host: api.amazonalexa.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.58.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Type: application/json
> Authorization: Bearer Atza|xxxxx
> Content-Length: 2
> 
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS updated)!
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/2 400 
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 110
< server: Server
< date: Thu, 26 Dec 2019 15:53:04 GMT
< x-amzn-requestid: 300413fa-09db-4a13-95a7-a4749ef5130a
< x-amz-date: Thu, 26 Dec 2019 15:53:04 GMT
< vary: Accept-Encoding,X-Amzn-CDN-Cache,X-Amzn-AX-Treatment,User-Agent
< x-amz-rid: 4TW7K1A311QVNFQ8M6BJ
< x-cache: Error from cloudfront
< via: 1.1 1a3a682cf8d843fe52f3224f60584fad.cloudfront.net (CloudFront)
< x-amz-cf-pop: MXP64-C1
< x-amz-cf-id: djdsKqkXYy8BOzvhZyD9G2iUXa8NeLscxBi45x4fs6EUc3C6tOrD6Q==
< 
* Connection #0 to host api.amazonalexa.com left intact
{"message":"Invalid request payload. Please ensure that the request payload has all required fields present."}
```

What I do not understand is why the Java library gets stuck in such cases.

All in all, my issue is *solved*.